# How to pin point the error point in Error "Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric"

Tags: sql, overflow, axapta, numeric

I have a SQL stored procedure which is throwing the following error

> Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric

I do understand that it is due to some calculation which is producing results that are exceeding the storage limit of the destination column.

But the stored procedure is very long and complex. Is there any way to pinpoint the point of problem ?

Thanks

Comment: Debut the procedure line by line.What is the Database you are using??

Comment: its a transnational database. I am working on Dynamics AX ERP solution's Database

Comment: print some text after every calculation so that you can identify from which part you are getting this error

Comment: Procedural code like stored procedures is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 1):

I have tracked the point of error.
There was a function being called in the script and it was returning a column which was being inserted into another table. The error was the difference of capacity of both columns data type. one was numeric(32,28) while other was numeric(19,2).
I found it by commenting the code chunk by chunk. and when i got the remaining code without error, I tracked the last code I commented and it gave me the concrete point of error.
**Thanks for the input guys**